# Javascript to pass a variable to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript in my html `<script>` :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var reason = prompt("Please enter reason:");
  if (reason == null || reason == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
  } else {
    txt = reason ;
  }
  document.getElementById("myField").value = txt;
  return txt
}
</script>
```

And im trying to pass the `reson` var to my HTML `input` like this :

```
<button class="button button" onclick="myFunction()"> <span class="blink"> {{button_name }}  </span> </button>
<input type="hidden" name="reason" id="myField" value=""/>
```

So when i click on a button, i get a prompt that ask for a "reason" and user is typing the reason , i want the `input` to return this value. it worked once and now it stopped.

How can i do this properly ?

**EDIT**:
full code update :

```
<ul>
<h2 style="font-family:verdana; text-align:center; font-size:200%;">Support</h2>
    {% for zone in zones %}
            <p style="font-family:courier; font-size:120%;"><strong><ins>"{{ zone }}" </ins></strong></p>
            {% for thing in value %}
            <form target="_blank" method="get" action="connection" style="display: inline;">
                    <input type=hidden name="client" value="{{ thing['client'] }}">             
                    {% if thing['zone'] == zone %}
                            {% if thing['ttl'] %}
                                    <button class="button button" onclick="myFunction()"> <span class="blink"> {{button_name }}  </span> </button>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="reason" id="myField" value=""/>

                    {% endif %}
               {% endif %}

           </form>

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

</ul>
```

Demo showing your problem:

```js
console.log('Single (first) element of your ID - length:', document.getElementById("myField").length);
console.log(document.getElementById("myField"));

console.log('\nCollection of elements named reason (printed in reversed order)');
var col = document.getElementsByName("reason");
console.log('- length:', col.length);
for(var i=col.length;i;) {
   console.log(col[--i].outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="reason" id="myField" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="reason" id="myField" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="reason" id="myField" value="3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="reason" id="myField" value="4"/>
<input type="hidden" name="reason" id="myField" value="5"/>
<input type="hidden" name="reason" id="myField" value="6"/>
```

Comment: I have just tried it locally and it works. Probably some other function is conflicting/overwriting the input value.

Comment: why you gave input type hidden?

Comment: Im passing it to python code so i need it hidden. @PrakashReddyPotlapadu

Comment: @SergiiVorobei Ill check again :\

Comment: whaterever is entered in the `prompt` is getting stored in input correctly. So what's wrong? `alert( document.getElementById("myField").value)` is giving me the value entered in ` prompt`

Comment: It's working for me. Just check duplicate id or duplicate function or something like that.

Comment: @gsr, I have replicated your code here https://codepen.io/manmur/pen/qBdjXZw .. Just removed ```type="hidden"``` for checks and it is working as expected only..

Comment: im not getting the value to my python, it worked befor ,  the button click is inside a `<form>` and pass to my python function, i have there `data = dict(request.args)` that gets all hidden values, but now it doesnt catch only the reason value.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I cannot remove the `hidden`, anyways i see the problem, i have a lot of buttons and its only work for 1 button for some reason... im checking why

Comment: Do you use unique ID(/s) ? There can be only single ID of a name, but multiple elements with equal name attribute. Also assignment in if looks opposite.

Comment: @Tom I dont use IDs at all only for this variable, i have a for loop that creates 100 buttons and this script only works for the first button. idk the reason why

Comment: Maybe a bit longer code could help us understand where could be your problem then...

Comment: @Tom I added the full loop that creating the buttons. it gets the vars from a python code

Comment: Final HTML would be way easier, but would tell you have ID problem - as you can see in a demo added as edit to your question.

Comment: @Tom so how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using particular form ?

There should be 2 options

- use DOM to find element near (may be broken when page structure changes or in different browser)
- send form as parameter and find your input on its form as it is common for button and input ?

```js
function myFunction(frm) {
  var txt;
  console.log(frm.reason.value); // 1st option
  console.log(event.srcElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.outerHTML) // 2nd option
  var reason = prompt("Please enter reason:");
  if (reason == null || reason == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
  } else {
    txt = reason;
  }
  frm.reason.value = txt; // 1st option
  console.log(event.srcElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.value == txt); // 2nd option
  return txt
}
```

```html
<form target="_blank" method="get" action="connection" style="display: inline;">
    <input type=hidden name="client" value="{{ thing['client'] }}">
    <button class="button button" onclick="myFunction(form)"> <span class="blink">button_1</span></button>
    <input type="notHidden" name="reason" id="myField" value="1"/>
</form>
<form target="_blank" method="get" action="connection" style="display: inline;">
    <input type=hidden name="client" value="{{ thing['client'] }}">
    <button class="button button" onclick="myFunction(form)"> <span class="blink">button_2</span></button>
    <input type="notHidden" name="reason" id="myField" value="2"/>
</form>
```

Comment: IE: event.srcElement -> button, event.srcElement.parentElement -> form, event.srcElement.nextElementSibling -> input and you can also pass this to the function (button) instead using event inside.

Comment: i cant do it like that, the for loop builds 100+buttons i cannot build each button sepertly and add its value, i need it dynamic